# Python whoosh to run add_document

Tags: python, whoosh

I have created an index and created documents as per documentation.

But when I am running the script do I always have to go through the process of adding the document and then search for the string.

Is it possible to store it once and then I can search for the terms again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created an index, you can reuse that index (assuming you've saved it).

In Whoosh, you can reopen a previously-generated index like so:

```
import whoosh.index as index
ix = index.open_dir("dir/to/index")
```

Here, `ix` is an `Index` object. The file path is the same you used to create the index using `create_in`. You can then create a `Searcher` object (`ix.searcher()`) and begin searching, just as you probably learned in the ["Quick start"](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/quickstart.html).

See ["How to index documents"](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/indexing.html#creating-an-index-object) for more information.

Comment: But when I do that my search are limited to 3. In case of create_in I get 6 results (I added a limit of 6)

Comment: Did you `commit` the written documents to the index? Also check for an issue in your application logic.

Comment: Yes I committed those documents. I will check. Thanks. Accepting this answer since earlier I wasn't getting any result at all.